# Regular Expression to find money in text

Tags: regex, currency-formatting

I need to find a regular expression that will extract any $ followed by an integer like $200 or $50 or $50.00 or $5,000 from a text.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try searching for regex expressions about particular things like money using a site like [this](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=money&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1).

Personally, I like the regex of

```
new Regex(@"^\-?\(?\$?\s*\-?\s*\(?(((\d{1,3}((\,\d{3})*|\d*))?(\.\d{1,4})?)|((\d{1,3}((\,\d{3})*|\d*))(\.\d{0,4})?))\)?$");
```

which will cover these: $0, 0, (0.0000), .1, .01, .0001, $.1, $.01, $.0001, ($.1), ($.01), $(.0001), 0.1, 0.01, 0.0001, 1., 1111., 1,111., 1, 1.00, 1,000.00, $1, $1.00, $1,000.00, $ 1.0000, $ 1.0000, $ 1,000.0000, -1, -1.00, -1,000.00, -$1, -$1.00, -$1,000.00, -$ 1, -$ 1.00, -$ 1,000.00, $-1, $-1.00, $-1,000.00, $(1), $(1.00), $(1,000.00), $ (1), $ (1.00), $ (1,000.00), ($1), ($1.00), ($1,000.00)

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work:

```
^\$(([0-9]*)|([0-9]{1,3}(\,[0-9]{3})*))(\.[0-9]{2})?$
```

If you use https://regex101.com/, you should be able to get a pretty decent explanation on it. Basically, we start with a dollar sign ($), and check for either a comma-separated whole number or a non-comma separated whole number, followed by an optional decimal part.

Comment: How would I handle multiple multiple currency symbols?